# $-3x^{2m}+7x^m-3$ is irreducible for all $m\geq 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I have heard that $p(x)=-3x^2+7x-3$ is the simplest polynomial for which $p(1)=1$, $p(x)=x^{\deg p}\cdot p(x^{-1})$ and $p(x^m)$ is irreducible for all $m\geq 1$.
I have tried to show the last part, i.e., the irreducibility of $p(x^m)$ but wasn't able to.

**My attempt**: The case $m=1$ is trivial, so assume $m\geq 2$.
Let $\alpha=\frac{7+\sqrt{13}}{6}$ be a root of $p(x)$ and let $\beta=\sqrt[m]{\alpha}$.
It suffices to show that $$[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=2m,$$
or equivalently $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]=m$, since this would imply that $p(x^m)$, being a polynomial of degree $2m$, is a minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now we are left to show $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)]=m$.
Since $\beta$ is a root of $x^m-\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)[x]$, this is equivalent to $x^m-\alpha$ being irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.
In light of [the answer given here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133581/when-is-xn-a-is-irreducible-over-f), we need to show that $\sqrt[k]{\alpha}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\zeta_m)$ for all $1<k\leq m$, where $\zeta_m=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{m})$. Here is where I'm stuck, however.

My another attempt was to simply assume $-3x^{2m}+7x^m-3=f(x)g(x)$ and reach contradiction via different methods (e.g., by reducing modulo 3) but I was not successful here either.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a section in the book "Polynomials" by Victor V. Prasolov, namely section 2.3.2, on *Irreducibility of certain trinomials*. It might be helpful.

Comment: Also one answer of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450723/if-fx-is-irreducible-is-fxk-irreducible) has a criterion such that $f(x^n)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @DietrichBurde. It seems like however the criterion of the post is exactly the part where I got stuck.

Comment: One could argue that $p(x)=2x^2-3x+2$ is even simpler example satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this in Eisenstein's fashion.

Suppose $-3x^{2m}+7x^m-3=f(x)g(x)$ for $f,g\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
Reducing mod $3$, we obtain $\overline{f(x)}\cdot\overline{g(x)}=\bar{x}^m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.
Since $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is a PID, up to signs we obtain $\overline{f(x)}=\bar{x}^k$ and $\overline{g(x)}=\bar{x}^l$ for $k+l=m$.
Since $f(0)g(0)=-3$, WLOG we may assume $g(0)=1$ so we have $(k,l)=(m,0)$.

So far we have
$$ f(x)=-3+a_1x+\cdots+a_mx^m+\cdots+a_nx^n,\\
g(x)=1+b_1x+\cdots+b_{2m-n}x^{2m-n}$$
for $a_i$ and $b_j$ all divisible by $3$ except for $a_m\equiv1$ mod $3$ and $b_0=1$.
Observe that the leading coefficient $a_nb_{2m-n}=-3$ of $fg$ is not divisible by $9=3\cdot 3$.
If $n>m$ then $a_n$ is divisible by $3$ so $b_{2m-n}$ is not divisible by $3$, which can only occur when $g$ is the constant polynomial $1$.
Thus we may assume $f$ and $g$ have degree $m$ and $a_m=1$, $b_m=-3$.
If we investigate the coefficient of $x^m$, however,
$$7=a_0b_m+a_1b_{m-1}+\cdots+a_{m-1}b_1+a_mb_0\equiv10\;\mathrm{mod}\;9$$
since $a_0b_m+a_mb_0=(-3)^2+1^2=10$ and all other $a_i$ and $b_j$ are divisible by $3$.
A contradiction.

Comment: @Sil $a_m\equiv1$ modulo 3.